# statusMessage is undefined in "res" - Node Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working with Node.js & Express.js and I need a route to show the status of the app.

```
router.get('/status', function(req, res) {
   res.send("status " + res.statusCode + " : " + res.statusMessage);
});
```

When I log `res`, both `statusCode` and `statusMessage` are `null`.

The result is status 200 : `undefined`

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: why database there's no database

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. Can you share more code or host it in sandbox

Comment: If `statusCode` is `null` why does the result show it is `200`?

Comment: That's why I ask the question ..

Answer (score 2):

> When I log res, both statusCode and statusMessage are null.

Look at your output:

> status **200** : undefined

`statusCode` is not `null`, it is `200`.

`statusMessage` is not `null` either, it is `undefined`. This is expected. Look at the [documentation for it](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_statusmessage):

> If this is left as undefined then the standard message for the status code will be used.

The default message won't be added until after the object has left your control. As far as I know, there is no way to find out what message it will get other than inferring it from the status code.

Comment: in the log, both of them are null

Comment: Ok I understand then can you tell me a way to construct to route to get current status of my back ?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing nothing wrong. Take a look the source code of `ServerResponse` [here.](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/058c5b81cdbabe8989a194ba5d388f4c230f4af6/lib/_http_server.js#L147)

As you can see, statusCode and statusMessage are initialized (line) as:

```
ServerResponse.prototype.statusCode = 200;
ServerResponse.prototype.statusMessage = undefined;
```

And because you are not modifying either of them, they are set to defaults.